# ERROR 1055 i fixed but why did it gave the error on the first place?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I've set the `username` as a unique key not null

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users`(
    `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `username` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `created_at` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NOW(),
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `uk_uname` (`username`)
);
```

But while trying to discover what i the most popular day where people sign in, i got an error.

```
SELECT  `username`,
        DAYNAME(`created_at`) AS `day` 
    FROM `users`
        GROUP BY `day`;
```

"users.username which is not functionally dependent on columns in group by clause"

so i searched through stackoverflow and most people were saying to disable the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`, but i don't want to disable it, why cant i learn how to use it?

to make the code work i had to add  `ANY_VALUE(`username`)` it worked.

an answer in another post:
" For other use cases: You don't necessarily have to disable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY Given a case like this, According to mysql docs, "This query is invalid if name is not a primary key of t or a unique NOT NULL column. In this case, no functional dependency can be inferred and an error occurs:" "

BUT didn't i made `username` as an unique key? why the error?

Comment: You're saying "takes these N rows that have the same value in this specific 'day' column, and group them together", then you're saying "Select *the* user of this group", but the database engine has not been given any indication that there is 1 user in that group, there could be 1 distinct user per original row that went into the group. That's why you need to explicitly tell the database engine that you don't care, like you did, or how *it* should care, like taking the one that would've been ordered first, or last.

Comment: A similar problem would be if I told you this: "Go out on the street and give me the first 5 people you find with hats. Then tell me the name" (note, not *names*, plural, but *name*, singular). That quizzical look you just gave me, that's what the database engine just did.

Comment: i see, as by try, it worked with MIN and MAX along with `username`, where i guess MIN being the first to the last on that `day` and MAX last to first?. Is there some kind of first/first() last/last()?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by first/first() or last/last(), you get the user with the "lowest" or "earliest" name, or the "highest" or "latest" name, depending on which terminology clicks for you.